# Convert a dataframe to a dictionary with custom keys

Tags: python

So say I have a csv with the following headers

"A","B","C","D","E"

None of the data columns in themselves can act as the key but A and B concatenated can.
I'd like to create a dictionary object with A+B as key and C,D,E as items
How can I do this in Python ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), particularly the part about helping others better understand or reproduce the problem with code and/or sample data and expected output.

Comment: Use tuples for the key `(A,B)` and values `(C,D,E)`